# Wrap Kendo UI into a Angular 2 component

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to get a regular Kendo UI widget (Editor) wrapper into an Angular 2 component.  Is this possible.  Has anyone done it?

I am aware of the Kendo UI 2 for Angular suite and I am using it already, but was wondering if the missing widgets can be still used with Angular 2.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing really.  This question came up this morning and I thought I do some research before dive into coding.

Comment: @yurzui: so, do you have any ideas on how to approach this?  Since my last message, I added all the kendo scripts and created a component that renders the editor, however, the resulting html is just a plain textarea, but the kendo editor.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is how I did it:

- First I included jQuery in Index.html.  I used the CDN link.
- Then I got the Kendo UI scripts I needed.  I used http://www.telerik.com/download/custom-download to create a smaller file.
- Then I created a component to wrap the kendo widget:

```js
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var $: any; //inject jQuery

@Component({
 moduleId: module.id,
 selector: 'editor',
 template: `
  <textarea>{{ text }}</textarea>
 `,
})

export class EditorComponent {
 @Input() text: string;
 @Output() onTextChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();

 constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {

 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
  var ta = this.elem.nativeElement.children[0];
  var self = this;
  $(ta).kendoEditor({
   tools: [
    "bold",
    "italic",
    "underline",
    "strikethrough",
    "justifyLeft",
    "justifyCenter",
    "justifyRight",
    "justifyFull",
    "insertUnorderedList",
    "insertOrderedList",
    "indent",
    "outdent",
    "createLink",
    "unlink",
    "insertImage"
   ],
   change: function () {
    self.onTextChanged.emit(this.value());
   }
  });
 }
}
```

- Then to use it, I just declare it as :

```html
<editor [text]="'Hello from the outside'" (onTextChanged)="editorTextChanged($event)" ></editor>
```

- and then I just handle the editorTextChanged event.

I know this is not exactly the Angular way, but it works.  If anyone has a better way of doing this, please share it here.

Thanks.